# money display won't update

Tags: javascript, html

When clicking `id="bigButton"` It's not updating the amount of money I have. Anyone know why?

```js
var money = 50
    var stickAmount = 0
    var clickValue = 1 + stickAmount
    window.onload = displayMoney();
    function displayMoney() {
        document.getElementById('totalCurrentMoney').innerHTML = "$" + money;
        document.title = "$" + money + " - Arsenal Clicker";
    }
    function click() {
        money = money + clickValue
        displayMoney()
    }
    function purchaseStick() {
        money = money - 50
        stickAmount = stickAmount + 1
        displayMoney()
    }
```

```css
.card-arangement {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 align="center">Arsenal Clicker</h1>
    <h1 id="totalCurrentMoney" align="center">$5</h1>
    <div class="card-arangement">
        <input type="image" id="bigButton" onclick="click()" src="Images/bigButton.png" height="500">
        <div>
            <input type="image" id="stick" onclick="purchaseStick()" src="Images/stick.png" height="100">
            <input type="text" id="stick" onclick="purchaseStick()" disabled placeholder="stick - $50" height="100">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `click()` is already defined on an input, and gets a higher priority than your method.

So, rename `click()` function name to `updateMoney`

```
<input type="image" id="bigButton" onclick="updateMoney()" src="Images/bigButton.png" height="500">

function updateMoney() {
    money = money + clickValue
    displayMoney()
 }
```

Comment: what do you by mean it's already defined on an input?

Comment: `input` element already has an inbuilt `click` method. It will be always given higher precedence than your `click`

Comment: so because it says ```onclick```?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: You can do `<input type="checkbox" onclick="alert(click.toString())">` to view inbuilt native click method

Comment: ah so its just because it was named click? Also, do you know how to make it so I can't just spam buy ```purchaseStick()``` without going in debt? Is there a way to make it not buy if it would put the money counter in the negatives?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237729/discussion-between-atramentis-and-navnath).